# CSS style checkbox label if <input> is inside <label>

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    One
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Two
</label>
```

I would like to change the label background for the checkbox checked state.

The issue is that the input is inside the label, so I can't use the good old `input[type=checkbox] + label {}`

I cannot change this markup, so I cannot easily just add `<span>` tag around the text.

Is there a way to change the label on `:checked` state?

Here is my work in progress fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kgpnbdzy/2/

Comment: There will/might be the [`:has(<selector>)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class in the future, but right now it isn't supported by any browser.

Comment: The title (and imho the description) asks for a CSS solution, hence why the JavaScript and jQuery tags? With JavaScript this would be easy.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas , I'm opened to suggestions, that's why I added the js tags ..

Comment: @Andreas would you be please able to edit my fiddle with the jquery solution?

Comment: Check the [dupe target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)